# How to fragment a video in HLS mp4 segment using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I know that ffmpeg is able to produce mp4 segment
(https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5699#no1), but i can't find how to do it :(

actually I do

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -hls_time 10 output.m3u8
```

but of course I have .ts segment and me I want .mp4 segment :(

Comment: Add `-hls_segment_type fmp4`. See other options at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5

Comment: thanks it's was this !

Comment: by the way for everyone interested -hls_segment_type fmp4 not work in ffmpeg right now, their are bug : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7023#ticket

Comment: Can you help me with the js code?

Answer (score 3):

FYI, as of May 2018, this appears to be fixed in ffmpeg v4:

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp://@:50000 -c copy -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list+split_by_time -hls_playlist_type event ~/Sites/foo/index_4000.m3u8
```

Comment: Can you help me with the js code?